# To break out main method in submethod without if-return or exception

Tags: java, exception, methods, return

I want to know if there is any way to break out the main method using its sub-method, but without throwing exceptions or returning a boolean.

For example

```
public void foo()
{
    System.out.print("Trying to break out foo");
    validate1();
    validate2();
    validate3();
    System.out.print("Validation success");
}

public void validate1()
{
    //todo: break out foo() if validation failed
}
public void validate2()
{
    //todo: break out foo() if validation failed
}
public void validate3()
{
    //todo: break out foo() if validation failed
}
```

No `if( validate1() ) return;`  in **foo()**.

No exception throwing in **validate1()**, **validate2()**, **validate3()**.

Is that possible?

Comment: What is the question behind what you're asking? Is this on a test somewhere?  Are you in the middle of taking the test?

Comment: break is associated with loops. return with returning from functions. WHere is the loop in your code?

Comment: What would be the benefit of such a mechanic? Why does it have to be without return values or exceptions?

Comment: Just wanna separate the main logic part and the error handling part. The main method only needs to validate without knowing how it actually did.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such way to do so. You must get the response to your calling method and then break out of the calling method.

```
public void foo()
{
    System.out.print("Trying to break out foo");
    if(!validate1()) {
        return;
    }
    if(!validate2()) {
        return;
    }
    ....
    System.out.print("Validation success");
}

public boolean validate1()
{
    try{
        ....
        if(...) {
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //Don't throw exception. Instead just return false.
        return false;    
    }

    // no errors and validation passed
    return true;
}
```

---

However, if you want the program to end, then you can simply do

```
public void validate1()
{
    //todo: break out foo() if validation failed
    System.exit(0); // abruptly close the program
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understood that he want to quit the calling method when some condition occurs in the called methods. Basically, the OP wants to make sure that other methods are not called and `foo()` methods terminates.

Comment: Downvoters please explain. I have updated my code and explained as per the OP requirements. Thank you...

Comment: @JimGarrison, I appreciate that you pointed out. I had earlier missed the part where OP mentioned about `not throwing exceptions`. I have updated the code.

Comment: I also think about System.exit(0); however, I just want to stop foo() when one of any validation fails, and not killing the main process.

Comment: That is not possible. The execution must return to the caller program.